# A planar graph $G$ is the dual of its dual if and only if $G$ is connected.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

That is, prove that a planar graph is the dual of it's dual iff it is connected.

I know that in order for this to be true, G must be isomorphic to it's dual (G'), but I'm not sure how connectedness is necessary for this proof. If isomorphism implies that G and G' have the same number of vertices connected in the same way, then wouldn't V(G) = V(G'), and E(G) = E(G') whether or not G was connected?

Comment: Hint: It follows from Euler's formula that every self-dual graph with $n$ vertices has exactly $2n − 2$ edges.

Comment: I post as a comment and now as an answer because my knowledge of graphs is essentially null. But isn't the dual of a planar graph always connected?

Comment: @Samuel: If you consider a tree, then this simple graph is certainly planar and connected, but why should it be self-dual? Do I miss something in your headline?

Comment: This is not true, that such graphs are self-dual (this means that a graph is isomorphic to its dual).  For example, take $K_{3}$, it is certainly connected, but the dual is $K_{2}$ (with repeated edges), definitely not isomorphic.  If you want to show that the "dual" relation is symmetric in this case (if $G$ is connected then the dual of the dual of $G$ is isomorphic to $G$) then this is a different question.

Comment: A planar graph is self-dual if it is isomorphic to its dual. So the title does not agree with the question.